# How Export Excel file after protecting column using php

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

Is it possible to protect few columns of excel file while exporting them, so user cannot make any changes in those columns accidentally.

Here the code by which I am exporting my excel file. I need to protect column 1,2,and 4 to be protected. Need guidance -

```
require_once('dbconfig.php');
$DB_TBLName = "admission";
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/
//create MySQL connection
//$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName where branch_id = '$branch' AND addmission_date between '$date1' AND '$date2'";
$sql = "select * from admission where $search branch_id = '$branch'";

//echo $sql;


//execute query
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$file_ending = "csv";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");
//end of printing column names
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
 $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }
?>
```

Thank you every body in advance and waiting for suggestions and reply

Comment: csv stands for _comma separated values_. Excel can read those, but it isn't an Excel file. Comma separated values can't do much but being values.

Comment: If you want to protect columns in an Excel file, then you must actually write a __real__ Excel file, either BIFF (.xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) format... use one of the PHP libraries capable of writing __real__ Excel files, such as [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Mark Baker `$file_ending = "csv";` but see this line `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");` and I am able to export the file in .xls format. But don't know how to protect the columns using code.

Comment: You __cannot__ protect cells in a csv format file, and simply changing the file extension and setting headers to pretend that its an Excel file does __not__ automagically make it one.... the file you're creating is still only a csv file

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you Mark for showing right direction, Then i must first learn how to export MySQL data to MS Excel then only I can use your recommended tool i.e. PHPExcel. If I'm still wrong then your guidance required which will be is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Excel file, but a CSV file. You are naming it "`.XLS`" and for the sake of Microsofts almighty it does what you expect.

But in a CSV file you can't have an further statements to what excel should do with columns. You need a more intelligent conversion to a pure Excel file like in [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Wikipage).

Comment: See I mention this line for checking as I planed for CSV file `$file_ending = "csv";` but see this line `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");` and I am able to export the file in .xls format. But don't know how to protect the columns using code.

Comment: It doesn't matter what ending you put on the filname and your local machin is configured to start Excel on all .xls. And Excel is treating the CSV as a spreadsheet. Actually, the format is given by the way you convert rows to character separated values in your while loop. That is plain CSV and it will not get an Excel file by renaming it.